# How can I get LESSPHP working with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, html, less

I'm trying to use the [WP-LESS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-less/) plugin along with the [toolbox theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox). I'm trying to migrate my static site over to wordpress, and I'd like to keep the HTML5 and LESS bits.

How can I get wordpress to compile style.less into style.css? Is there a right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read documentation for WP-LESS?

If not, this might help:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-less/faq/